# What makes electrons behave like particles or waves at different times?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons, wave-particle-duality

I am quite puzzled about the theory that electrons or light often behave as particles and sometimes as waves. So, I wanted to know more about this phenomena and what happens when and why.

Comment: Hi Diyanko, this has been asked many times. The link ACuriousMind suggests probably gives the best discussion, though [a search of the site will find many more related questions](http://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=wave+particle+duality).

Comment: [LMGTFY](https://www.google.co.in/search?client=opera&q=wave-particle+duality&sourceid=opera&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8)! Have you checked the wikipedia? If you want an insight, then you may start reading [The Feynman's Lectures on Physics III's Quantum Behaviour](http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/III_01.html).